# Convert memory image to base64 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

trying to create pdf file using pdf package then convert it to an image and then convert the image to base64 to save it in a QR code. this should be a simple task for URL images and gallery images. But in my case, the image is generated in the flutter from pdf `doc`  as a memory image.  my code is

`await for (var page in Printing.raster(await doc.save(), pages: [0, 1], dpi: 72)) {final reciptimage = page.toImage();}`

tried the below code but it doesn't work

```
final bytes = await Io.File(reciptimage).readAsBytes();
```

I couldn't find any way to generate base64 from the memory image `reciptimage`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

may this eample can help you.

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
    ByteData byteData =
        await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    String bs64 = base64Encode(pngBytes);
```